# JS How to change var on page scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added an auto-scroll feature to my page that uses this code below to index through my navigation buttons.

note: all sections are 100vh and contain a class called .hash

Page Nav btn

```
<a href="#about" data-target="btn2" title="">About</a>
```

Auto-scroll btn

```
        <div id="autoScroller">
            <div id="up" onclick="section--; currentSection();"></div>
            <div id="down" onclick="section++; currentSection();"></div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var maximumSections = $('.hash').length;
var section = 1;
function currentSection(){
if (section > maximumSections){
    section = 1
} else if (section < 1){
    section = maximumSections
}
    $("a[data-target='btn"+ section +"']").click();
}
```

I also use this bit to auto adjust my url when a new section is scrolled to

```
$(document).bind('scroll',function(e){
$('.hash').each(function(){
    if (
       $(this).offset().top < window.pageYOffset + 20
    && $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > window.pageYOffset + 20
    ) {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('data-location');
    }
});
});
```

My next step is where I am getting stuck. 
Currently if you scroll to the bottom of the page manually, then click the down auto-scroll button, it scrolls to section 2 because the var section hasn't updated from its initial state of var section = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i figured it out!

```
        window.section = $(this).attr('data-btn');
```

I added a "data-btn" attribute to all the sections and gave them a value from 1 - 5

Then added this line under the "data-location" line on my bind function.

Seems to work. Thank you to anyone who tried this. I have no idea if this is good practice but I don't get an error and it works!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {adjustSection()};
var lastScroll = 0;
function adjustSection() {     
    if (document.body.scrollTop > lastScroll ) 
       section++;
     else 
       section--;   

   lastScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: This didn't work for this application. I really just need a way to redefine the section variable from inside the bind logic.